# Searching a text file in Swift

Tags: swift, search

I am having a hard time figuring out what is the most optimal way for me to search a text file in Swift? This text file is a dictionary with an entry on a new line with roughly 110000 lines and around 80 characters in each line.

So far what I have done is that I've read and saved the text file at run time, and I'm attempting to write a search algorithm or is there one in the library?

Also would the run time be too long if my search algorithm went through every single line of the dictionary as I can't do binary search since the file isn't sorted. Or should I sort each line first then run a search on it?

Comment: You can read file using `let databuffer = filemgr.contentsAtPath(filepath)` then you can covert NSData to NSDict somehow if it is json file you can easily convert but if its not you have to find some way.

Comment: & for searching inside NSData this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834787/find-character-string-in-binary-data , it might not be the fastest way but you can try.